# How to use different fonts for two lines within the same cell in Excel?

Tags: python, vba, excel

I have an excel file with a table A6:E233. I had to concatenate columns A and B so that values from B are displayed in a new line. I have achieved that with the CONCATENATE function (and CHAR(10) for new line) that is built into Excel.

After concatenation the spreadsheets looks like this:

[EXAMPLE1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AA8xT.png)

Now i would also need different formatting for each line inside the cell, namely size 12, bold for the first line and size 8 for second line:

[EXAMPLE2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsT7x.png)

How do achieve this? If it would be a short table, I would do it manually, but since I have a few files, totally well over 5000 rows, maybe an automated way would be better.

I have found answers that touch upon this problem, but since I dont know how to use VBA, I am more or less lost. I am also using a lot of python and have looked through openpyexl and csv, but have not found a way how to achieve this.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: openpyxl won't help you here, it doesn't show mixed cell formatting.

Answer (score 1):

With Excel VBA, you need to use the `Characters` property of the `Range` object. For example:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim lngPos As Long

    'get cell
    Set rngCell = Sheet1.Range("A1")

    'find linebreak
    lngPos = InStr(1, rngCell.Value, vbLf, vbBinaryCompare)

    'format either side
    rngCell.Characters(1, lngPos).Font.Bold = True
    rngCell.Characters(lngPos + 1, Len(rngCell.Value) - lngPos).Font.Color = 1234

End Sub
```

Which will format like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this code. I built this according to your screenshot.

```
Sub partialFormatting()

Dim tws As Worksheet

Dim fr, lr As Integer

Dim pos As Integer


    Set tws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    fr = 7

    lr = tws.Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row


    For r = fr To lr

        With tws.Range("A" & r)

            pos = InStr(.Value, vbLf)

            With .Characters(Start:=1, Length:=pos - 1).Font
                .FontStyle = "Bold"
                .Size = 12
            End With

            With .Characters(Start:=pos + 1, Length:=Len(.Value) - pos).Font
                .FontStyle = "Normal"
                .Size = 8
            End With

        End With

    Next r


End Sub
```

Please let me know if you have any questions on how the code works!